# Communicating with child processes using pipes, redirection and filestreams

Tags: c, unix, pipe

I'm having some difficulty implementing inter-process communication in C. I have simplified my problem to the following block of code, wherein I create pipes, fork the process, and redirect the IO for the child:

```
int main(void) {
    int parentToChild[2];
    int childToParent[2];
    pid_t pid = 1;
    char buffer[80];
    FILE *writeStream;
    FILE *readStream;

    pipe(parentToChild);
    pipe(childToParent);

    pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0) { // I'm the child. I read from stdin, and write to stdout.
        close(parentToChild[1]);
        close(childToParent[0]);
        dup2(parentToChild[0], 0);
        dup2(childToParent[1], 1);
        close(parentToChild[0]);
        close(childToParent[1]);
        fgets(buffer, 80, stdin); // wait for the parent to send something
        fprintf(stderr, "I got %s\n", buffer); // tell the world I got it
        fprintf(stdout, "Child message\n"); // send message back to the parent
    }

    if(pid != 0) { // I'm a parent
            close(parentToChild[0]);
            close(childToParent[1]);
            /* writeStream connected to stdin of child */
            writeStream = fdopen(parentToChild[1], "w");
            /* readStream connected to stdout of child. */
            readStream = fdopen(childToParent[0], "r");
            fprintf(writeStream, "Hello, World!\n");
            fgets(buffer, 80, readStream); // comment this out and the child will be able to read the "Hello World". Why is this?
            fprintf(stderr, "Parent just got %s", buffer);
    }



    return 0;

}
```

If I execute this, the parent just seems to wait on the child forever. Is there anything obviously wrong with how my streams are configured? If I have it so the child is reading only and the parent is writing only (or the other way around), it works fine, but I can't manage having both processes read-and-write. The order seems fine, with the child expecting stdin first and the parent writing first.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I `fflush (writeStream)` after the parent's  `fprintf(writeStream, "Hello, World!\n")` everything works fine.
I believe there is a problem with the buffering of the pipe.

Try to look at `man 3 setvbuf`

> setvbuf() function may be used on any open stream to change its buffer.  The mode argument must be one of the following three macros:
>
> ```
>          _IONBF unbuffered
>          _IOLBF line buffered
>          _IOFBF fully buffered
> ```

so I guess that setting your writeStream to `_IONBF` (unbuffered) would solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

From `dup2` man page:

> After a successful return from one of these system calls, the old and new file descriptors may be used interchangeably. **They refer to the same open file description**

Thus, closing one of the pipes closes one of the standard file descriptors. Don't do that.